# Perceptual image hashing

Tags: c#, image, hash, ocr

OK. This is part of an (non-English) OCR project. I have already completed preprocessing steps like deskewing, grayscaling, segmentation of glyphs etc and am now stuck at the most important step: Identifcation of a glyph by comparing it against a database of glyph images, and thus need to devise a robust and efficient perceptual image hashing algorithm.

For many reasons, the function I require won't be as complicated as required by the generic image comparison problem. For one, my images are always grayscale (or even B&W if that makes the task of identification easier). For another, those glyphs are more "stroke-oriented" and have simpler structure than photographs.

I have tried some of my own and some borrowed ideas for defining a good similarity metric. One method was to divide the image into a grid of M x N cells and take average "blackness" of each cell to create a hash for that image, and then take Euclidean distance of the hashes to compare the images. Another was to find "corners" in each glyph and then compare their spatial positions. None of them have proven to be very robust.

I know there are stronger candidates like SIFT and SURF out there, but I have 3 good reasons not to use them. One is that I guess they are proprietary (or somehow patented) and cannot be used in commercial apps. Second is that they are very general purpose and would probably be an overkill for my somewhat simpler domain of images. Third is that there are no implementations available (I'm using C#). I have even tried to convert pHash library to C# but remained unsuccessful.

So I'm finally here. Does anyone know of a code (C# or C++ or Java or VB.NET but shouldn't require any dependencies that cannot be used in .NET world), library, algorithm, method or idea to create a robust and efficient hashing algorithm that could survive minor visual defects like translation, rotation, scaling, blur, spots etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already tried something similar to this, but it may still be of some use:

https://www.memonic.com/user/aengus/folder/coding/id/1qVeq

Comment: Thanks man. Yes, I have gone through this very article before. But as the author tells: "However, if there are modifications -- like text was added or a head was spliced into place, then Average Hash probably won't do the job. While pHash is slower, it is very tolerant of minor modifications (minor being less than 25% of the picture)." OCR images more often than not have slight (sometimes severe) transformations.